# According to days change homepage or results

Tags: php, laravel

i have a two tables, days and posts.

Days table

```
id  |  day  
----------
1   | Day1
2   | Day2
3   | Day3
4   | Day4
5   | Day5
6   | Day6
7   | Day7
8   | Day8
9   | Day9
10  | Day10
11  | Day11
12  | Day12
```

Posts table

```
id  |  day  |  posts
---------------------------
1   | 1    |  Day1Text
2   | 1    |  Day1Text
1   | 1    |  Day1Text
2   | 2    |  Day2Text
1   | 2    |  Day2Text
2   | 3    |  Day3Text
1   | 4    |  Day4Text
2   | 5    |  Day5Text
```

I have a 12 days and each days have a different posts, every day at 10.00 am this change, example Today(Day1) and only 1st day posts will appear. Tomorrow at 10.00 am 2nd day posts will appear. When the 12th day ends, this loop will return to the beginning and start again 1st day. How can i do this?

Comment: What information do you need on Carbon? Is there anything you've tried so far? If so, can you show the code for this? Your question is quite vague at the minute.

Comment: İ need something like this
`if(Carbon::now() == "Monday")
        {
            $results = Post::where('Day', 'MONDAY')->get();
        }elseif (Carbon::now() == "Tuesday") {
            $results = Post::where('Day', 'TUESDAY')->get();
        } elseif (Carbon::now() == "Wednesday") {
            $results = Post::where('Day', 'WEDNESDAY')->get();
        }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off you want to know how to cycle over the posts as days go by. As input we need at least 12 different days, so we can use the current day of the month or year. If we take the day of the year:

```
Carbon::now()->dayOfYear  //e.g. int(137)
```

We can now calculate its mod against the number of posts, which will always return a number between 0 and 11. If we add 1 we'll have a number between 1 - 12. E.g:

```
137 % 12 = 5  // 5 + 1 = 6
120 % 12 = 0  // 0 + 1 = 1
347 % 12 = 11 // 11 + 1 = 12
```

At this point, we know what post we need to display each day, but we're not controlling the hour it should start displaying.
To fix this, one way would be to consider the days change at the time you want the posts to change, aligning both makes things easier. As we don't want to offset the server timezone, we can just offset the date we pick by 10h meaning that a new day will begin once the current day gets to 10AM:

```
Carbon::now()->subHours(10)->dayOfYear
```

Now we can use the resulting mod value to build the necessary query to display the post.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's what i need. I'm going to do a different system in order not to have a problem in the future. I'm thinking of adding post to the database for each day with timestamp. Show today's writings at 10:00 every day. Show yesterday's record if it was not 10.00 am.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it you don't really need the if statement so for this you could either use the `englishDayOfWeek` [getter](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-getters) or just use php's [date format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

i.e.

```
$results = Post::where('Day', now()->englishDayOfWeek)->get()
```

or

```
$results = Post::where('Day', now()->format('l'))->get()
```

Comment: This gave the result as I wanted, but I could not do exactly what I wanted. There is a 12-day process, 12 days after the end of the same things will return to the day and day will show. And this must be at 10:00 every day. Example, 1st day at 10.00 am, show "a, b, c", when comes 2nd. day at 10.00 am show "d,e,f". When the 12th day comes, then go to day 1.

Comment: @TechnoBeceT I'm sorry but I really don't know what you mean "12 days after the end of the same things will return to the day and day will show". Please can you update your question with exactly what you want with more detailed examples and things like your db structure and an example data set.

Comment: I've updated the question, I hope I can tell you what I mean.